# How to drop all coordinates and variables without dimensions in xarray

Tags: python-xarray

How can I drop all xarray Dataset coordinates and variables that don't have any dimensions? In this example, I want to drop `item` and `nothing` from this Dataset.

```py
import xarray as xr

ds = xr.Dataset(
    {"temperature": (["x", "y"], [[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]), "nothing": 10},
    coords={"item": "hi", "x": [1, 2, 3], "y": [1, 2, 3]},
)
ds
```

[image]

I could of course use `ds.drop_vars(["item", "nothing"])`, but I was expecting a different method like `ds.drop_dims()` or `ds.squeeze()` could do this without me specifying which to drop.

An alternative way to look at this question is, how can I select only coordaintes and variables where the dimension is `(x,y)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xarray doesn't have exactly what you are looking for but something like this should work:

```
ds.drop_vars(lambda x: [v for v, da in x.variables.items() if not da.ndim])
```